# Is there any way of avoiding magic numbers in annotation attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have this code, all over in different instances, using the `RequiredIf` attribute from [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com)

```
[Display(Name = "ID Number")]
[RequiredIf("CitizenshipId", 1)]
public string IdNumber { get; set; }
```

But what I really want is

```
[RequiredIf("CitizenshipId", GetId("SA Citizen")]
```

Now, as I think a quillion other developers would also like, is to eliminate the magic number 1 So far, all I think of is a string name for a lookup function parameter that function must lookup up. And making a 1 into a "1" is plain bad.

**NOTE:** Constants are not ideal here, as the magic number abovr refers to a DB's PK. I suppose this isn't ideal either, and I should add a third column with a 'constant code' for each lookup entry, so matter what the PK and no matter what the text, we still have one immutable values.

**NB NOTE:** I'm working inside Orchard, so no funny business with custom providers.

Comment: Attribute arguments can be `const` members.

Comment: It would better refer to these as *magic values* because they can be of any constant in-place defined values.

Comment: @ani, in this case the magic number is a PK, which is why I want to look it up and not code it as constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [FluentValidator](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which is more flexible than Attributes. Definitely easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use constants.

1. Existing attributes can't be changed.
2. For attributes, generics are not supported.
3. Lambda expressions can't be used since attribute constructors (and properties) may only contain constant expressions